# Search in nested list where number between range

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I have below nested list called `row_list`:

```
[[
        {
            'text': 'Col',
            'x0': Decimal('21.600'),
            'x1:' Decimal('30.000')
        },
        {
            'text': '1',
            'x0': Decimal('41.600'),
            'x1': Decimal('51.600')
        }
    ],[
        {
            'text': 'Col',
            'x0': Decimal('21.600'),
            'x1': Decimal('51.600')
        },
        {
            'text': '1',
            'x0': Decimal('41.600'),
            'x1': Decimal('51.600')
        },
        {
            'text': 'Col',
            'x0': Decimal('200.736'),
            'x1': Decimal('210.296')
        },
        {
            'text': '2',
            'x0': Decimal('230.600'),
            'x1': Decimal('240.920')
        }
]]
```

Where each nested list, represent a text line. So the above represents:

```
Col 1        
Col 1           Col 2
```

Now consider that I have two defined areas `(x, y, w, h)`, that I want to use to "split" up the list (much like table columns). For example:

```py
areas = {}
areas[0] = (0, 0, 100, 792)
areas[1] = (100, 0, 300, 792)
```

With the above, I want to select all the text that is within the defined area (no matter what nested list it belongs to). That should give me:

```py
[[
        {
            'text': 'Col',
            'x0': Decimal('21.600'),
            'x1': Decimal('30.000')
        },
        {
            'text': '1',
            'x0': Decimal('41.600'),
            'x1:' Decimal('51.000')
        },
        {
            'text': 'Col',
            'x0': Decimal('21.600'),
            'x1:' Decimal('30.000')
        },
        {
            'text': '1',
            'x0': Decimal('41.600'),
            'x1:' Decimal('51.600')
        }
    ],[
        {
            'text': 'Col',
            'x0': Decimal('200.736'),
            'x1': Decimal('210.296')
        },
        {
            'text': '2',
            'x0': Decimal('230.600'),
            'x1': Decimal('240.920')
        }
]]
```

I am a bit unsure of how I can search/select in nested lists, and "remap" the data. I have tried something like:

```py
finalCols = []
for i, area in enumerate(areas):
    area = areas[i]
    for line in row_list:
        for word in line:
            if word['x0'] >= area[0] and word['x1'] <= area[2]:
                finalCols[].append(word)
```

But that simply just appends each word to a list, and not created the nested list structure like above (my expected output).

Comment: What is the question ? Does your code work ?

Comment: @gaFF updated my question with my code so far. Expected output is also in my question

Comment: In the inner loop you need to create a new row_list.

Comment: @Stark do you mind showing a short example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  Should be something like:

```
finalCols = []
for area in areas:
    for line in area:
        newWords = []
        for word in line:
            if word['x0'] >= area[0] and word['x1'] <= area[2]:
                newWords.append(word)
        finalCols.append(newWords)
```

Comment: I get this error: `NameError: name 'NewWords' is not defined` on the line `5` in above.

Comment: I cleaned it up a little

Comment: Check spelling of `newWords`.  Note that if you want the double outer list you may to do the same thing in the middle loop with newLines = [], etc.

Comment: Also please recall that python assignment does not do deep copy, so the leaves in finalCols are the same data as was in areas.

Comment: But this also appends an empty list `[]` if there is nothing to append. It should only append if the word is within the area.

Comment: Add: `if newWords:` before the append to make it skip empty lists

Comment: Also I think you may have an extra level in your code. `area` is each list in the outer list. `line` is each dict in the inner lists, so it should probably be `line['x0']` and get rid of the innermost loop.